# Three.js raycast intersection with Line

Tags: three.js, line, raycasting

I would like to ask why the intersection with raycast on lines doesn't work properly in THREE.js (it detects intersection even though I just clicked near the line).

I use following code to create a line:

```
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
});
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-2, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 0));
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
```

And then for the raycast part I do the following:

```
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
```

Intersects returns me intersection with line even when I click near it.

Comment: Have you tried to use [.linePrecisiion](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster.linePrecision) property?

Comment: You might want to check out this example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_lines

Comment: @Prisoner849 yep, that was the problem.. I didn't see that you have to set it in order to detect line intersections. Thanks!